# Pass scheduled timestamp to celery beat / redbeat

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a question i am trying to find an answer for a while.
I'm using Celery Beat in a production environment since the last year.
I switched to Redbeat as Beat handler to be able to add and remove tasks dynamically.

The problem is simple, if I schedule a task at a time X is there a way to pass X to that task?

For example,
if a task is scheduled at 11:00 is there a way to pass that time to that task as an argument?
This would be super useful, because if that task for whatever reason (consumer worker not running) is not executed at 11:00 but at 11:30, I can know inside the task that the original desired scheduled time was at 11:00 and not 11:30!

If you know a solution for that, maybe also using Redbeat, let me know please, it would be crazy helpful!
Thank you!

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind is to enable task-sent events and then grab this information inside task itself. To be frank I do not know if that is possible or not, but it is worth checking.